# What is the kind of this graph?

Tags: graph

2 days ago, I have a test.
This is the one of the problem.

The problem is :

Select the kind of the graph.

[image: http://imgur.com/zcQcyfb (I'm sorry but I have low reputation)]

1. Undirected Graph
2. Directed Graph
3. Complete Graph
4. SubGraph
5. Weight Graph

The answer was 5.
But I think the answer is also 1.

What do you think of this problem?

1 is correct? or 5 is correct? or 1 and 5 are both correct?

Young min

Comment: @user2864740 oh ... the irony ... :D ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29#Undirected_graph

Comment: @user2485710 Good counter. Anyway, play the school game - the teacher didn't draw the numbers or say "pick one" for nothing :)

Comment: ask yourself if an Undirected Graph can possibly be mistaken for a Weight Graph and viceversa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

maybe a venn graph could help you understand the relationship. 1 -> undirect  2 -> direct 5 -> weight
your answer lies in the shaded area.